# Total Shares for Facebook + Wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm new here, but I have used this website a lot to find solutions on my questions. Now I dont see any possible ways to not ask here by myself, cause I cant find any solution on this problem at all.

In **functions.php** I have this written:

```js
function get_likes($url) {
$fakecount = "209";
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$count = intval( $json[$url]['shares'] ) + $fakecount;

echo "$count";
}
```

Which as you see, get the total *shares* amount from Facebook. To output this number, I have this in my **single.php**:

```html
<span class="countshare"><?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo get_likes($url); ?></span>
```

But the output for this is only the fakecount (209), the Facebook Shares will not be added in + of this number. If I remove the fakecount, the output is 0.

Whats strange, is that sometimes it gets the right amount of shares (it works), but sometimes not. Like now, it hasnt been working for over 12 hours, so there is definitely something wrong here.

I would appreciate it a lot if you can take yourself time to help me!

I'm looking forward to see your replies...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really fully understand what you are saying but maybe it is something to do with how often facebook updates that info in the public api.

Comment: Well, some plugins have the updated count every time, but when I do it in this way it often shows "0" or my fake count "209".

Comment: It can be to do with whether you are going to the fully qualified url www  .yoursite.com or yoursite.com without the www